# Excel VBA send e-mail with variable number of attachments

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba

I am trying to write some VBA code that will open outlook and attach all the PDFs in a certain folder to the email. I know how to do it for one item, but since I don't know how many items the folder will contain, I need to somehow attach all PDFs in the folder. I followed another tutorial on how to do it but I get the run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Edit: The error comes up at the .From line but happens for every line for the application.

I double checked and I have the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library installed and active in the project. Is there anything super obvious that I'm missing here?

```
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim StrFile As String, StrPath As String

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

StrPath = "H:\Desktop\TEST_PDF\"

With OutLookMailItem
    .From "GroupMail@company.com"
    .To "GroupMail@company.com"
    .Subject "MACRO TEST"
    .Body "TEST MESSAGE"

    StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        .Attachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    .Display
End With

Set OutLookApp = Nothing
Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
```

Comment: Which tutorial you've followed? Which line gives the error?

Comment: I tried to find it again but I haven't been able to find the page. It was a thread in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find `MailItem.From` property anywhere. Besides that, I am not sure why you have 0 in your `CreateItem`. Moreover, you need `=` in front of `OutLookMailItem` properties to assign values (*e.g.* `.To = "GroupMail@company.com"` is the correct form).

If you want to send an email from a different account, you have two options that I know of; either using `.SentOnBehalfOfName` property which your account should have *"Send As permission"* (it seems you are trying to used Group Mail, so that looks like an option). Or you can use `.SendUsingAccount` property (I think that's what you mean by `.From`).

Amazing [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) explained these in his blog post. I include it here, with some more commentary, to be a future reference on SU.

If you're using `SendUsingAccount`, you probably want to identify the account numbers and making sure that you have access to them (signed in, etc.) using the macro below;

```
Sub Which_Account_Number()
'Don't forget to add a reference to Outlook in the VBA editor
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim i As Long

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For i = 1 To OutApp.Session.Accounts.Count
        'I prefer using Debug.Print instead of MsgBox
        MsgBox OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(i) & " : This is account number " & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

When you figured out what account you want to use, you can proceed to next step which is the actual process of sending an email.

```
Sub Mail_Change_Account()
'Only working in Office 2007 and higher
'Don't forget to set a reference to Outlook in the VBA editor
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim strbody As String, StrFile As String, StrPath As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    StrPath = "H:\Desktop\TEST_PDF\"
    StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    'You can use the account number or as the actual account address
    'Here I'm Assuming that you have access to GroupMail@company.com account...
    'on the system you are running this macro
    '(We used account address but the syntax...
    'for using account number is below as a comment as well)
    'Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
     Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts("GroupMail@company.com")

    'You may want to comment-out the line below first to see the errors explicitly for now
    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "GroupMail@company.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "MACRO TEST"
        .Body = strbody
        .SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
        '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "HR-Mail@company.com"

        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            .Attachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop

        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutAccount = Nothing
End Sub
```